# How to correctly send data to json via php?

Tags: php, json

I am working with Mailchimp API, and trying to pass the user name from my form to the list.

Mailchimp has a nested structure for an actual user name, and I don't understand how to correctly write code for it.

The JSON data structure looks like that:

```
{
"email_address": xxx@xxx.com
"merge_fields": {
"FNAME":
"LNAME":
  }
}
```

To send the post request the script using a function with post method

```
$result = $MailChimp->post("lists/$mailchimp_list_id/members", [
                    'email_address' => $subscriber_email,
                    'status'        => 'subscribed',
                  //'merge_fields'['FNAME'] => $subscriber_name; 
            ]);
```

I try to send `'merge_fields'['FNAME'] => $subscriber_name;`

Can anyone explain me how to get inside the JSON with PHP?

Comment: if you don't know much more about `json`, make `array structure` of your input value in PHP and use `json_encode()` to get data in json format.

Comment: try like this json_encode(array('test' => 'value1')); json_encode will convert your array to json format

Comment: Actually is that JSON what is returned to you from mailchimp, or what mailchimp requires as input? Should have ask this before I answered

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
$jsonArray  = json_encode(array('0' =>'test','1' => 'test2'));
```

`json_encode` will convert your php array to json format 
If you want to decode your json array to php array then use `json_decode`

```
$phpArray = json_decode('Any json encoded array');
```

Answer (score 0):

First create a PHP data structure to match the required JSON structure and then `json_encode()` that structure.

The `{}` means object in JSON
The `[]` means array in JSON

```
<?php
    $inner = new stdClass();
    $inner->FNAME = $subscriber_first_name;
    $inner->LNAME = $subscriber_last_name;


    $member = new stdClass();
    $member->email_address = 'xxx@xxx.com';
    $member->merge_fields = $inner;

    $json_string = json_encode($member);
```

Comment: I am getting the following result with your code: "email_address":"xxx@gmail.com","merge_fields":{"FNAME":"Igor"},"status":"subscribed", but for some reason it is not passing Mailchimp validation(

Comment: Sorry I Cannot help with the MailChimp part, I have never used it

Comment: This code worked:  $result = $MailChimp->post("lists/$mailchimp_list_id/members", [
                'email_address' => $subscriber_email,
                'status'        => 'subscribed',
                'merge_fields'  => array(
                    'FNAME' => $subscriber_name,
                    'LNAME' => null,
                    ),

        ]);

Comment: You had better remove the Accept from this answer as it has nothing to do with how you solved your issue. Otherwise it will just confuse others that might find your question

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this is the best way to work with JSONs in PHP:

1. Add this to get the full JSON Body:

   ```
    $json = file_get_contents('php://input');
   ```
2. Validate the json. I work with the Respect Validator.
   https://github.com/Respect/Validation/blob/master/docs/Json.md

   ```
           if(v::json()->validate($json)){

              $whatever = new whatever($json);
           }
   ```
3. Normalize the json object with a php class
       class whatever{
           public $email;
           public $merged_fields;

   ```
       function __construct($json){
           $json = json_decode($json);

           if($json->email){
               $this->email = $json->email     
           }else{
               echo "Error";       
           }
       }
   }
   ```
4. Use jsonSerializable for encoding. This is a really good HowTo:
   http://www.sitepoint.com/use-jsonserializable-interface/